# How to update .Net domain service from entity model?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, service, dns

I have not found a way to update a .Net domain service after I changed the underlying entity model.

So when there are changes to the model I create a new domain service as workaround and copy my properties/methods from my old domain service to it.

Is there any easier and maybe less error prone way?

Comment: Is this WCF RIA Services with siverlight? if so please tag as such

Comment: @Ian Ringrose As far as I know this applies to every application using Ado.Net. In fact in my case I work on an offline WPF application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the best thing I found are partial classes. In addition to the automatically created DomainService.cs I add a DomainServiceProtected.cs where my implementations I don't want to have overwritten every time something changes in the entity model reside.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a snippet that really helps out with this problem. Check my answer here:

[Adding additional entities to a Entity Framework backed Domain Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193036/adding-additional-entities-to-a-entity-framework-backed-domain-service/7014222#7014222)